# Problema con funcion hash

Tags: javascript

Tengo que encontrar cuál es el string x que, al aplicarse a la función hash, produciría como resultado el siguiente número entero: 468484901136871.

```
function hash(x) {
seed = 11;
diccionario = "acefimoprstuv";
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
seed = (seed * 23 + diccionario.indexOf(x[i]));
}
return seed;
}
```

El string x es una palabra de 10 letras que se compone por "acefimoprstuv" se pueden omitir y reutilizar las letras las veces que sean necesarias.
Necesito ayuda para resolverlo ya que no me aparece lo que devuelve el return.

Answer (score 1):

Return no te funciona porque están sin definir seed y diccionario. El siguiente código arregla esa parte.

```js
var x = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
function hash(x) {
let seed = 11;
var diccionario = "acefimoprstuv";
for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
seed = (seed * 23 + diccionario.indexOf(x[i]));
}
return seed;
}
console.log(hash(x));
```